# Odd results following code in Head First C

Tags: c, file-io, io-redirection

I'm doing the exercises in a book, [Head First C](http://oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=0636920015482). I double-checked that my code is the same as in the book and I'm carefully following the steps in the book.

The C file is supposed to take gps data and format it in JSON style.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    float latitude;
    float longitude;
    char info[40];
    int started = 0;

    puts("data=[");
    while (scanf("%f, %f, %39[^\n]", &latitude, &longitude, info) ==3) {
      if (started) 
        printf(", \n");

      else 
        started = 1;

          printf("{latitude: %f, longitude: %f, info: '%s'}", latitude, longitude, info);
    }
    puts("\n]");
    return 0;
}
```

First the book had us type in the data, to show us how tedious and poorly formatted it looks, then we learn to redirect stdin to read a file of comma-separated data, like so:

```
$ ./geo2json < gpsdata.csv
```

I couldn't find source files online so I copy/pasted from the pdf of the book to create the csv file.

```
gpsdata.csv and gpsdata.txt

42.363400,-71.098465,Speed = 21 
42.363327,-71.097588,Speed = 23
42.363255,-71.096710,Speed = 17
42.363182,-71.095833,Speed = 22
42.363110,-71.094955,Speed = 14
42.363037,-71.094078,Speed = 16
42.362965,-71.093201,Speed = 18
42.362892,-71.092323,Speed = 22
42.362820,-71.091446,Speed = 17
42.362747,-71.090569,Speed = 23
42.362675,-71.089691,Speed = 14
42.362602,-71.088814,Speed = 19
42.362530,-71.087936,Speed = 16
42.362457,-71.087059,Speed = 16
42.362385,-71.086182,Speed = 21
```

Weird stuff happened, so I went thru the lines and deleted then re-entered the line breaks in case there was some hidden formatting. I tried changing the file type from .csv to .txt. Neither made a difference. When I typed in the data, this weirdness did not happen.

How it's supposed to look:

[image: formatted data from the book]

How it actually looks. Note how the last line is different. BTW sometimes the 'l' in latitude shows up on that last line.

```
login:~/programming/cfiles> ./geo2json < gpsdata.csv
data=[
'}, itude: 42.363400, longitude: -71.098465, info: 'Speed = 21
'}, itude: 42.363327, longitude: -71.097588, info: 'Speed = 23
'}, itude: 42.363255, longitude: -71.096710, info: 'Speed = 17
'}, itude: 42.363182, longitude: -71.095833, info: 'Speed = 22
'}, itude: 42.363110, longitude: -71.094955, info: 'Speed = 14
'}, itude: 42.363037, longitude: -71.094078, info: 'Speed = 16
'}, itude: 42.362965, longitude: -71.093201, info: 'Speed = 18
'}, itude: 42.362892, longitude: -71.092323, info: 'Speed = 22
'}, itude: 42.362820, longitude: -71.091446, info: 'Speed = 17
'}, itude: 42.362747, longitude: -71.090569, info: 'Speed = 23
'}, itude: 42.362675, longitude: -71.089691, info: 'Speed = 14
'}, itude: 42.362602, longitude: -71.088814, info: 'Speed = 19
'}, itude: 42.362530, longitude: -71.087936, info: 'Speed = 16
'}, itude: 42.362457, longitude: -71.087059, info: 'Speed = 16
'}atitude: 42.362385, longitude: -71.086182, info: 'Speed = 21
]
```

I checked the online errata and didn't see anything about this. I was using Cygwin but then tried linux, both had the same result.

Any help or insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Hm, this is not JSON. Not even the supposed output is JSON.

Comment: I don't know much about json but the output file that came out formatted correctly did work in the map app that was the next step.

Comment: It may have worked, but it's still not JSON. JSON dictionaries have their keys wrapped in double quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file contains Windows-style [CRLF line endings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations) and your program is not equipped to deal with them. The authors of this book have assumed a Linux or Mac machine (LF newlines) without testing on Windows-style text files. The result is that each line's carriage return (CR) character is still contained in the string `info`, which screws up the output.

You can modify the program to scan for both CR and LF characters by

```
scanf("%f, %f, %39[^\r\n]", &latitude, &longitude, info)
```

Note the `\r`.

(You say you tried this on Linux, but I guess you used the input CSV file that you made on Windows?)

Comment: Yes I used the same file but I somehow thought if that was the problem that re-ending my lines would help. I guess not. Your solution worked. Is there any other way to avoid this, or is this the best workaround?

Also I'm still stumped as to why the formatting turned out as it did, leaving out characters and stuff.

Comment: @punstress: if you want portability, I think this is the workaround. I'm wondering how you re-ended the lines; for me, `unix2dos` was enough to reproduce the problem and `dos2unix` was enough to solve it. (Both commands are available on Linux and should be available on Cygwin.)

Comment: I just backspaced to delete the line endings then hit enter again. I guess that was pretty dumb to think it changed anything but I was more thinking that there might be something else hidden there from the pdf. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
while (scanf("%f, %f, %39[^\n]", &latitude, &longitude, info) ==3) {
```

to

```
while (scanf("%f, %f, %39[^\n\r]", &latitude, &longitude, info) ==3) {
```

I think you may have returns in your input file (was it from a Windows box?).